# What technology exists that could activate a small circuit upon high acceleration/impact?

Tags: switches, accelerometer, piezoelectricity

The circuit will fit inside a 12 gauge shotgun shell, be fired from it (with less gunpowder), and will have DC batteries. I'm wanting to conserve battery life until the shot is fired. When fired, I want the switch technology to activate the circuit which will remain live for a long time. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know if anything you build inside a shell including a battery can survive the explosive shock without damage? It should be enough to shear wirebonds and short battery cells.

Comment: it might be cheaper/more feasible to activate upon loading rather than firing...

Comment: As @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 pointed out, the switch in this case might be the easy part of this design. This kind of force can shatter the silicon itself in your chips.

Answer (score 3):

WW2 anti aircraft proximity shells solved this by having a glass container of acid that broke when the shell was fired activating the battery, very neat as the shelf line of the battery was a problem, and this solved it by assembling the battery at the time of firing.

The other nice win was that the time it took for the battery to come up and heat the filaments in the valves (yes they managed to make valve based AA shell fuzes that survived the acceleration), provided range safety because the thing would not become sensitive until a few seconds after launch.

I am sort of wondering about something like this with a zinc/air cell as the battery?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is a setback switch using a [Belleville washer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belleville_washer). The washer contains a contact which is pushed backwards by the launch acceleration, and the snap action causes it to stay in position once activated.

It has almost perfect isolation before activated (depending on the insulator material), so it has no battery drain.